# get size of scrollviews scrollable area in titanium

Tags: android, ios, titanium, scrollview

I have a scrollview that has for example width = 200. But the scrollable region is much beggar then 200.

How can I get the size of the scrollable region from my scroll?

I have tried to create a variable and each time I add a new object to my scroll my variable increments the child objects size. But it's not working like I need.

Comment: You should be Abe to ask the Scrollview for it's contentSize, from which you should be able to determine the height or width

Comment: I have tried this: scroll.getContentWidth() (my scroll is vertical) but I receive always 'auto' and that is not what I need.